# (Mac)Vim always does autocomplete (even whitelines)

Tags: vim, macvim

Somehow my macvim/vim instance is expanding every tab to the autocomplete menu, this prevents me from tabbing my code.. I really dont have a clue about the why.

My vimrc is here: https://github.com/jvanbaarsen/dotfiles/blob/master/vimrc

a screenshot of the problem:

[image]

(the "happens" text, is the first appearance in the autocomplete list, i tabbed on a newline though)

I hope someone can help me, this is driving me insane!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had found this online and used it in my vimrc to "fix" the problem.  But it was still kinda a pain, so I just retrained myself to use `ctrl-p`.  not the url in the comment was valid at one time, but is not longer..

```
" Remap the tab key to do autocompletion or indentation depending on the
" context (from http://www.vim.org/tips/tip.php?tip_id=102)
function! InsertTabWrapper()
  let col = col('.') - 1
  if !col || getline('.')[col - 1] !~ '\k'
    return "\<tab>"
  else
    return "\<c-p>"
  endif
endfunction
inoremap <silent> <tab> <c-r>=InsertTabWrapper()<cr>
inoremap <s-tab> <c-n>
```

Comment: Thanks this one has a bit more context :)

Answer (score 0):

I think i found the problem, it was the 'ervandew/supertab' bundle, after removing it, i was able to use vim normally.

Answer (score 0):

The `supertab` plugin aims at both keeping usual indentation functionality of `<Tab>` key and completing with it. I personally don’t use it using self-written function instead, but possible causes of your issue are described in the very first question in the FAQ placed in the README file available right at [project homepage](https://github.com/ervandew/supertab):

> - **Why isn't supertab honoring my configured settings (attempts to complete at the start of a line, always performs keyword completion instead of my configured default, etc.)?**
>
>   Chances are that you have a very old version of snipmate installed, or something similar, which will issue a <c-n> when no snippet is found. Supertab use to map to <c-n>, so this behavior would act as a fallback to supertab, but current versions of supertab no longer do so, resulting in snipmate bypassing supertab entirely.
>
>   You can check if this is the case by running the following in vim to see what is mapped to <tab>:
>
>   ```
>    :verbose imap <tab>
>   ```
>
>   To resolve the issue you can either:
>
>   1. Install my [fork](https://github.com/ervandew/snipmate.vim) or
>   2. Upgrade to a more recent snipmate fork, like [garbase/vim-snipmate](https://github.com/garbas/vim-snipmate)
>
>   See [#74](https://github.com/ervandew/supertab/issues/74) for additional details.